# Issue connecting custom queue driver laravel 5.1 'No connector for [mysql]'

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, queue, laravel-5.1

I have searched the query all over internet but till have not come up to the solution for this issue. `No connector for [mysql]`

I have 2 Mysql Connections `mysql` and `mysql2`. `mysql` is to store data and `mysql2` to store `QUEUE JOBS`.

Here below is the .ENV file details.

```
 DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_DATABASE=laravel_5_1
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=mysql_queue
```

As you can see the about connection is `DB_CONNECTION=mysql` and my Queue driver `QUEUE_DRIVER=mysql_queue`

I have assigned and new queue driver named `mysql_queue` in queue.php

below is the queue.php code

```
 'default' => env('QUEUE_DRIVER', 'mysql_queue'),

'connections' => [
'mysql_queue' => [
            'connection' => 'mysql2',
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'table' => 'jobs',
            'queue' => 'default',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
]

'failed' => [
        'database' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql_queue'),
        'table' => 'failed_jobs',
    ],
```

As you can see the `mysql_queue` has `'connection' => 'mysql2',` were i would like to store queued jobs.  `mysql2` is a new connection assiged in database.php below is the code.

```
'mysql2' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'laravel_5_1_queue'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],
```

Even after making these major changes as per laravel documentation i still get `'No connector for [mysql]'` Error and unable to run `QUEUED JOBS` in background. kindly suggest me.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: check this post https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/11051

Comment: @Bilal Ahmed i have tried to the above link and in many different ways. But still show `No connector for [mysql]` error.

Comment: ok. then clear cache and config using these commands `php artisan config:clear`, `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: @Bilal Ahmed  now i'm getting this error : `No connector for []`. Now i have specified connecitons and queue driver also used `config:clear` and `cache:clear` commands